# Photo Library Organization With Catalina

Tags: photos, catalina

What happened `Photos Library.photoslibrary/Masters` after upgrading to Catalina? It appears to have been replaced with `originals` and reorganized by uuid or something that obliterates dates in the folder hierarchy?

Comment: I upgraded to Catalina recently and noticed the same. I can no longer see Masters folder and there is a new originals folder instead. I search a lot about this online but found no information or discussion about it other than this question on AskDifferent.